# Vb.net bindingsource.filter from a list of strings

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

i have in a windows.form a combobox and a datagridview,
i add rows in datagridview with a button and get the value(string) from combobox and if i double click on the row of datagridview i delete the row.

When i add the row i want to hide/disable/remove the combobox value and when i delete the row i want to restore it in combobox.

The combobox values are binding from dataset source and combobox is dropdownlist style.

I try some things until now but this is what i think is better approach and where i am:

```
Dim filterList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

Private Sub filterListAdd()

        Dim dgResult As String
        filterList .Clear() 'Clear the list so no duplicates

        For i As Integer = 0 To combobox.Items.Count - 1
            Dim a As String = combobox.GetItemText(combobox.Items(i))

            For row As Integer = 0 To Dgview.RowCount - 1
                For col As Integer = 0 To Dgview.ColumnCount - 1
                Next
                Surname = Dgview.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value.ToString
                If dgResult = a Then 
                    filterList .Add(a) 'Add to list
                End If
            Next
        Next i

    End Sub   

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click

Dgview.Rows.Add(combobox.Text)
filterListAdd()

'Here i want to bindingsource.filter = filterList 

End Sub

Private Sub Dgview_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Dgview.MouseDoubleClick

Dgview.Rows.Remove(Dgview.CurrentRow)

'I Guess here with the same way i filter it again

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Panos

Comment: To be clear, you want items in the grid to not be displayed in the `ComboBox` and items that are not in the grid to be displayed in the `ComboBox`.  Correct?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, in short words. I have problem doing it because the items in Combobox are binding in dataset.

Comment: Why can't you bind both the grid and the `ComboBox` and then you can "move" items from one to the other simply by updating two `Filter` properties?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I search a little and i think i can't do it, the grid is unbound because it take other items. You give me a other idea to do it with bindingsource.remove and bindingsource.add without update the dataset. I am looking if it can work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think i got it, for now it works, i post the answer if you think something else pls tell me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

Dim clsItems As New ArrayList()

Private Sub RemoveComboItem()

Me.BindingSource.Position = Me.BindingSource.Find("1", Combobox.Text)
Dim 1Add As String = DirectCast(BindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Item("1").ToString
Dim 2Add As String = DirectCast(BindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Item("2").ToString
Dim 3Add As String = DirectCast(BindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Item("3").ToString

      clsItems.Add(New MyItem(1Add, 2Add, 3Add))

      BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

  End Sub

Private Sub AddComboItem(dg As DataGridView) ' Because i have two datagridviews

      Dim 1 As String = dg.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()

      For i = 0 To clsItems.Count - 1
          If i <= clsItems.Count - 1 Then
              If 1 = clsItems(i).1 Then
                  Dim drNewRow As DataRow
                  drNewRow = DeeDataSet.Tables("Table").NewRow()
                  drNewRow("1") = clsItems(i).1
                  drNewRow("2") = clsItems(i).2
                  drNewRow("3") = clsItems(i).3
                  DeeDataSet.Tables("Table").Rows.Add(drNewRow)
                  clsItems.Remove(clsItems(i)) ' Remove it from array so no duplicates
              End If
          End If
      Next

  End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click

RemoveComboItem()

End Sub

Private Sub Dgview_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Dgview.MouseDoubleClick

AddComboItem(Dgview)
Dgview.Rows.Remove(Dgview.CurrentRow)

End Sub

End class

Public Class MyItem

  Private m_s1 As String
  Private m_s2 As String
  Private m_s3 As String

  Public Sub New(1As String, 2 As String, 3 As String)

      M_sName = 1
      M_sSurname = 2
      M_sTitle = 3

  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property 1

      Get
          Return m_s1
      End Get

  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property 2

      Get
          Return M_s2
      End Get

  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property 3

      Get
          Return M_s3
      End Get

  End Property

End Class
```

In that form i don't update the dataset because every change i want to make it in other form, so when i finish from here the dataset.table has no changes.